# How to feed lists from python into javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, for-loop

I'm pretty new to Javascript. I was wondering, how does importing lists generated by Python work? Below is a rough version of what I'm thinking, I'm trying to import 3 lists into an HTML file using javascript (apologies in advance if any of the syntax is off.):

```
function createMarkers(){
  //import article_list generated by headline.py
  //import urls from generated by headline.py
  //import coordinates generated by headline.py
  for (i = 0; i < 25;) {

  article_name = article_list[i]
  url = urls[i]
  coordinate = coordinates[i]

  var marker[i] = WE.marker([coordinate]).addTo(earth);
  marker.bindPopup("<b>article_name</b><br><a href="url">url</a>, {maxWidth: 520, closeButton: true});
  }

}
```

Do I need to implement some sort of web framework to execute the python code and feed it into this javascript code? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How do you run the javascript? If it is executed in the client browser (which it normally is if you don't use node.js or rhino or something) you cant run the python code from there as you dont have access to the client machine. In that case you need to make an AJAX call to the web server that can execute the code for you and feed it back to the client. This will depend on your server side implementation as well of course. How do you serve your application?

Comment: I was hoping to use a VPS like Digitalocean to host and run the Python code. The javascript is in an HTML document. Does this mean I need to do an AJAX call (whatever that is)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into templating languages? I have solved a similar problem using Jinja2.

Here are some [Docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/).
Here is a [Quickstart](http://kagerato.net/articles/software/libraries/jinja-quickstart.html) tutorial.

Below is an example.

The variable markers is injected into the HTML, using Jinja2

**Python code:**

```
import webapp2 # Le framework
import json    # This is used to return the dictionary in a native (to JS) way
import jinja2  # The glue

# This example uses webapp2, but could be easily adapted to other frameworks.
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    # sets the folder "templates" as root folder for html (can be tweaked to match you layout):
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates')) 

class Marker():
"""
creates marker objects that can then be rendered on the map.
"""

def __init__(self, latlng, title):
    # below we split the comma-separated latlng into two values and store in an array.
    coords = str(latlng).split(',')
    self.lat = coords[0]
    self.lng = coords[1]
    self.title = title

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # assembling the coordinates and descriptions into an array of Marker objects
        markers = []
        for marker in list_of_markers:
            markers.append(Marker(latlng="coordinates go here in format 'latitude, longitude'",
                                  title="Marker title goes here")

        for marker in markers:
           t_dict = {}
           t_dict['m_title'] = marker.title
           t_dict['m_lat'] = marker.lat
           t_dict['m_lng'] = marker.lng
           temp.append(t_dict)
        json_markers = json.dumps(temp)

        template_values = {'markers' :json_markers}

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

# Initializing the webapp:
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=False)
```

**Javascript code:**

```
// To be added to the initialize() function of the maps JS:
data = {{ markers }} 

// Iterating over list of points to create markers:
data.forEach(function(p) {
     var point = new google.maps.LatLng(p.m_lat, p.m_lng);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point,
         map: map,
         title: p.m_title,
         //animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     });
 });
```

Comment: Great thanks! I hadn't heard of the language ever before... so it's pretty new, but I'll give it a shot. Sounds exactly like what I need! Is this different than Python or Flask?

Comment: @PythonScraper This example uses webapp2 instead of Flask, but the two are highly interchangeable (at least, for this task). If you would like an example that uses Flask, just leave a comment. :)